# There is a way to create non-web Java app on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, heroku, desktop-application

There is a way to create non-web Java app on Heroku? I's my first time using the Heroku application, I know just how to upload the app, but how can I configure the same to run as desktop application and non-web?

Disclaimer: I tried to understand it in the Heroku documentation, but at first glance, it got too confusing for me...

Comment: It depends what you mean by "non-web". You can have _workers_, per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile, but it sounds like you're looking for more of a remote desktop.

Comment: What I want is basically to upload a java binary that will update the database that my api, which is hosted on heroku, accesses. Does this fall under the workers? It's basically a database update routine.

Comment: These words are all pretty loaded. When _I_ see "desktop application" I imagine something with a GUI that runs on the machine I'm sitting in front of, outside of a browser. You can't do that on Heroku since Heroku's code runs on its dynos. But if it's something you can schedule to run in the background, without a GUI and without user interaction, you should be able to do that on Heroku. That's the kind of thing workers are good at.